# Hammer a nail into my chin if

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

Hammer a nail into my chin, if it ever happened.
Informally they say,
Spit on my grave if it ever happened.

Someone who is so confident that his following statement is irrefutable and cannot be gainsaid. He would precede by saying it. It's to persuade and convince.
I'm looking for a formal way of saying this in English.

Hammering a nail into one's chin is in some parts of the Arab World goes back to a pre-Islamic custom that shames people.

Comment: "I'll be damned if" is probably the most common, and "I'll eat my hat if" quoted below is another possibility, but I wouldn't call them *formal*. Are you sure you are looking for a formal phrase? Both "hammer a nail into my chin if" and "spit on my grave if" do not strike me as formal. And arguably the whole idea as such is informal in nature. You just don't write a PhD thesis in mathematics saying things like "may God strike me down if my formula is wrong".

Comment: It's found in Arabic prose. Every language is different.

Answer (score 3):

A close equivalent is the (apparently initially British) usage, ‘**I’ll eat my hat** [if something-or-other turns out to be true].’  The usage is still current, even now that actual hat-wearing is far less common than it used to be.

[This article](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/eat-my-hat.html) offers several possible historical derivations for the expression.